# Ошибка подключение к базе данных

Tags: java, debian, jdbc

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема с установкой подключения к локальной базе данных, используя `JDBC` драйвер. При попытке установки соединения выдается ошибка:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Запускаю я программу на Debian 8 командой: `java -jar name.jar`. Перепробовал уже несколько способов решения проблемы:

1. Добавлял через Maven библиотеку `mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.41` и добавлял ее внутрь артефакта (jar файла).
2. Скачивал библиотеку командой `sudo apt-get install libmysql-java` и добавлял ее в CLASSPATH `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar`.
3. Клал саму библиотеку рядом с моим jar файлом и добавлял в MANIFEST.MF: `Class-Path: mysql-connector-java.jar`

IDE - intellij Idea Ultimate 2017.1

ОС, на которой выполняется jar файл - Debian 8

Возможно, кто-то уже решал подобную проблему. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

UPD:

Ошибка выдается в данной строке:

```
Class.forName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
```

где `DATABASE_DRIVER`

```
public static final String DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

Comment: Думаю стоит включить в вопрос код, который вызывает `ClassNotFoundException`. Также поясните, пожалуйста, насчет «... и добавлял ее внутрь артефакта...». Вы имеете ввиду она сама добавлялась в собранный JAR?

Comment: @defaultlocale обновил вопрос, добавив код. Под фразой «... и добавлял ее внутрь артефакта...» я понимал то, что в IDEA я заходил "File - Project Structure - Artifacts" и добавлял эту библиотеку в Output Layout, выбирая из Available Elements.

Comment: Покажите листинг своего jar файла

Comment: @Barmaley листинг - список файлов, входящих в jar файл?

Comment: @defaultlocale я не знаю, почему Вы удалили свой комментарий, но он действительно помог. Я не очень хорошо знаком с Unix и не знал, что так можно сделать. Пожалуйста, оформите свой комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @ahgpoug я толком не понимал, почему это может сработать и по ходу редактирования запутался и удалил коммент. Но вот, вроде Бармалей все толком объяснил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема здесь вот в чем:

Если *jar* является *executable*, то при указании ключа `-jar` все остальные упоминания о `CLASSPATH` в виде `-cp` и проч. игнорируются. Считается, что весь `CLASSPATH` находится внутри jar архива. Соответственно выхода 2:

1) Вручную указывать через `-cp` где искать `main` класс и там же указывать путь на драйвер, типа:

```
java -cp name.jar:mysql-connector-java.jar com.somepackage.subpackage.Main
```

2) Запаковать внутрь `name.jar` драйвер - можно вручную распаковать jar драйвера и засунуть, а можно через утилиту [jarjar](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar)

Comment: Верно, согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html): «When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.»